# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server (110) AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-rds, ubuntu-20.04

What I have tried so far:

1. Changed bind-address in mysqld.cnf to 0.0.0.0 (as well as to the exact ip address returned by
   **nslookup xxxxxxxxx.us-est-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306**, though I have reverted it back to 0.0.0.0) and restarted mysql
2. Configured inbound/outbound rules of the RDS instance security group to accept all traffic on all ports
3. Created locally the mysql user corresponding to the global RDS username

```
$ mysql -u root -p


mysql> DROP USER admin@localhost;
mysql> DROP USER admin@'%';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> CREATE USER admin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'admins_password'
mysql> CREATE USER 'admin'@'%'
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;

$ mysql -u admin -p -h xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

4. Changed the RDS instance to public
5. Enabled ufw and ensured 3306 is allowed
   `
   However, I am still getting the error

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' (110)

It goes without saying that most of these changes are not advisable from a security perspective but I am only trying (and failing) to get a connection at the moment. Any help would be much appreciated.